# Regular Expression to get content in statement

Tags: html, css, regex, youtube

Example : I have HTML code as below,

```
<p ><strong>PM Narendra Modi visits BJP headquarters</strong>[youtube-video id='XHDUCalVmis' width='640' height='360' ]</p><hr />
```

here I want to select only

```
[youtube-video id='XHDUCalVmis' width='640' height='360' ]
```

part. Thought regular expression will work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the simplest, this regex will match your string:

```
\[[^\]]+\]
```

**Explanation**

- `\[` matches an opening bracket
- `[^\]]+` matches one or more chars that are not a closing bracket
- `\]` matches a closing bracket

Comment: Thank you zx81 for your quick response . Will try your suggestion .

Comment: You're very welcome, let me know if it works, and if you have questions. :)

Comment: Sorry, Tried but its not working :( No output only..             This is php code i am trying with                               <?php
$pgm_time="<p ><strong>PM Narendra Modi visits BJP headquarters</strong>
[youtube-video id='XHDUCalVmis' width='640' height='360' ]</p><hr />";

preg_match_all('\[[^\]]+\]', $pgm_time, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>

Comment: You're missing a regex delimiter (we'use `~`) in your `preg_match_all` (and it looks like the backslashes are missing too, unless that's a problem with the comment form): try `$matchcount = preg_match_all("~\[[^\]]+\]~", $pgm_time, $matches);` Let me know if that does it. :)

Comment: Hi Z881, It is working as expected  :) Thank you so much for your time .. I have to got through regular expression tutorial :(:D

Comment: Yes, something like `$regex = '/\[[^\]]*?id=\'\K[^\']+/m';
if (preg_match($regex, $yourstring, $m)) {
 $thematch = $m[0];
    } 
else { // no match...
     }
`

Comment: Hi @zx81.. I have another requirement on regular expression..I have HTML Code like this                                             <meta property="og:site_name" content="The Indian Express" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Modi likely to draw the largest crowd ever by a foreign leader in&nbsp;US" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://images.indianexpress.com/2014/09/modit1.gif?w=209" />....etc   here i want to get the content of meta property=og:image ie here 'http://images.indianexpress.com/2014/09/modit1.gif?w=209' ...    Please help me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: 
regex: .*?(\[.+\])
Capture the group 1, will get you the square bracket part.

If you need a more detail answer, please provide more info.

p/s: [This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a great tutorial for regular expression, I recommend reading through it.

Comment: Thank you MikeNQ for your quick response and suggestion.